# Is there any script or code to open android apps using programs?

Tags: python, output

As I am New to programing i started using my smartphone as an idle device where i do simple coding.And i wanted to creat a program to open any app installed on my android device using subprocess module. For that i have used the following code
import subprocess
subprocess.call(playstore.apk)
But the output comes with error:[Output of the program I've mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rtlH.jpg)

Comment: Please place the output in the question so we can all see it

Comment: , sorry for your inconvinence, i have tried this for 1st time so i the next question i will